# Getting a TYPE ERROR and dont know how to solve the question

Tags: python, python-3.x

High Schooler here, i need help with a question. I have to count the number of vowels in a sentence and output the total no. of vowels along with the word with the most vowels. But I'm getting ***TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple*** And cant really figure out how to solve it.

```
string = 'This is a string'
vowels = 'AaEeIiOoUu'

string = string.split(' ')
for i in enumerate(string):
    word = string[i]
    count = [x for x in word if x in vowels]

print(vowels)
print(len(vowels))
```

Comment: `enumerate()` returns a tuple of index and item. You should change your `for` statement to: `for i, word in enumerate(string):` or something similar and remove the line below. Since you don't need the index in the loop your can just simply everything with a `for word in string.split():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While iterating `enumerate` it always uses a two-parameter(tuple). One is index and the other is an iterable object. Use a contemporary variable after `i` to iterate the `string`.

```
for i,s in enumerate(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate() method adds a counter to an iterable and returns it in a form of enumerate object. You need to add a second variable in `for i in enumerate(string)` as follows:

```
string = 'This is a string'
vowels = 'AaEeIiOoUu'

string = string.split(' ')
for i, char in enumerate(string):
    word = string[i]
    count = [x for x in word if x in vowels]

print(vowels)
print(len(vowels))
```

OUTPUT

```
AaEeIiOoUu
10
```

Answer (score 0):

First: If you are going to use enumerate, then it will always return a tuple in the iteration. The first element of the tuple will be the index, the second element will be the value.

For example:

```
for i, word in sentence.split(' '):
```

This will return the index, string tuple as follows:

```
(0, 'This')
(1, 'is')
(2, 'a')
(3, 'string)
```

While you can use this, I think you may find the below answer useful.

I see that you are already using list comprehension in your code. You can do all of it in one line.

```
sentence = 'This is a string'
vowels = 'aeiou' 
#you dont need to check for both upper and lower. just use .lower()

count = sum(True for word in sentence.split(' ') for x in word  if x.lower() in vowels)
print (count)
```

Explanation:

First you are iterating each word in the sentence : `for word in sentence.split(' ')`

Next you are using another loop to check for each character in the word against the vowel `for x in word if x.lower() in vowels`. Note: You don't really need to check for AaEeIiOoUu. You just need to check for one of this set either uppercase or lowercase.

If the value is found, return `True` which is equal to `1` to the sum function.

Wrapping all this with a `sum()` statement will give you the count as you are summing the `True`s.

Also, you are printing the vowels and length of vowels. That will always be a constant as you have `AEIOUaeiou`. The length of this will always be `10`. I think your intention was to find out the count of vowels in the sentence. That value is in the variable `count`